# Pandas cut method generates wrong category for values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, categories

I have following dataframe.

```py
d = {'id': [1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20], 'score': [23.4, 10.1,30.3,31.4,27.4,15.4,47.2,45.7,35.9,12.4,50.7,26.9,10.5,8.3,26.7,63.2,2.3,28.7,36.3,11.4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

id  score
1   23.4
2   10.1
3   30.3
4   31.4
5   27.4
6   15.4
7   47.2
8   45.7
9   35.9
10  12.4
11  50.7
12  26.9
13  10.5
14  8.3
15  26.7
16  63.2
17  2.3
18  28.7
19  36.3
20  11.4
```

I am creating category where range is 25.

```py
score_range= ["[{0} - {1})".format(r, r + 25) for r in range(0, 100, 25)]
score_range
['[0 - 25)', '[25 - 50)', '[50 - 75)', '[75 - 100)']
```

I categorised the values of column 'score' based on the range and got the following output:

```py
df['score_range'] = pd.cut(x=df['score'], bins=len(score_range), labels=score_range)
df
id  score   score_range
1   23.4    [25 - 50)
2   10.1    [0 - 25)
3   30.3    [25 - 50)
4   31.4    [25 - 50)
5   27.4    [25 - 50)
6   15.4    [0 - 25)
7   47.2    [50 - 75)
8   45.7    [50 - 75)
9   35.9    [50 - 75)
10  12.4    [0 - 25)
11  50.7    [75 - 100)
12  26.9    [25 - 50)
13  10.5    [0 - 25)
14  8.3 [0 - 25)
15  26.7    [25 - 50)
16  63.2    [75 - 100)
17  2.3 [0 - 25)
18  28.7    [25 - 50)
19  36.3    [50 - 75)
20  11.4    [0 - 25)
```

'score' value 47.2, 45.7, 35.9, 36.3 fell into [50-75] range, and 63.2,50.7 fell into [75-100] range, which should not be.

47.2, 45.7, 35.9, 36.3 should fall into [25-50] range, and 63.2,50.7  should fall into [50-75] range!

Why does Pandas.cut method generates wrong category?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The categories are wrong, because you are passing the incorrect argument to `bins`. As it stands you pass an integer to bins, so the behavior is:

> int : Defines the **number of equal-width bins in the range of x**.

You need to pass it a `sequence of scalars`:

```
df['score_range'] = pd.cut(x=df['score'], bins=range(0, 125, 25), right=False)

    id  score score_range
0    1   23.4     [0, 25)
1    2   10.1     [0, 25)
2    3   30.3    [25, 50)
3    4   31.4    [25, 50)
4    5   27.4    [25, 50)
5    6   15.4     [0, 25)
6    7   47.2    [25, 50)
7    8   45.7    [25, 50)
8    9   35.9    [25, 50)
9   10   12.4     [0, 25)
10  11   50.7    [50, 75)
...
```

Comment: great! So I need to add one extra bin for the upper boundary? But why the other values fall into right range?

Comment: @studentcoder Yes, since they are edges, you will need one more than the number of bins. You need 4 edges to define 3 bins: `| x | x | x |` (bins being `x`, edges being `|`)

Comment: Great explanation!

Answer (score 3):

Why not using `pd.cut` without self-created those labels , also when you create the bins you may need adding one bins size for the upper boundary

```
pd.cut(df.score, range(0, 125, 25))
```